# How can we implement in app update in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, ota

I want to implement in-app-update or on-the-air update which means whenever the user opens the app, it checks and automatically downloads a new chunk of code and merges it, and asks the user to restart like most of the games (COD, PUBGm) do.

**NOTE** : I'm not talking about [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update)

I tried to find out the basic workflow but could not.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: Flutter mobile (android, ios)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that what you need is what [Firebase Remote config](https://firebase.google.com/products/remote-config) does, you can read about it and get more details from its [Flutterfire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/remote-config/overview/)

Comment: Yes. Needed something like this. Are there any other services available except firebase?

Comment: Yes, a similar service is available on https://www.back4app.com/ and https://parseplatform.org/ and https://docs.growthbook.io/